# checkbox em campo de matriz dinâmica

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

Encontrei um código em uma das perguntas do forum, segue:

```
    function criarTabela(conteudo) {
  var tabela = document.createElement("table");
  var thead = document.createElement("thead");
  var tbody=document.createElement("tbody");
  var thd=function(i){return (i==0)?"th":"td";};
  for (var i=0;i<conteudo.length;i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for(var o=0;o<conteudo[i].length;o++){
      var t = document.createElement(thd(i));
      var texto=document.createTextNode(conteudo[i][o]);
      t.appendChild(texto);
      tr.appendChild(t);
    }
    (i==0)?thead.appendChild(tr):tbody.appendChild(tr);
  }
  tabela.appendChild(thead);
  tabela.appendChild(tbody);
  return tabela;
}
document.getElementById("tabela").appendChild(criarTabela([
  ["id", "nome",     "idade"],
  [1,    "matheus",  16],
  [2,    "cristian", 16],
  [3,    "pedro",    10],
  [4,    "henrique", 10]
]));
```

Ele é do membro [Matheus Cristian](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/21416/matheus-cristian) e tenho uma dúvida sobre ele. Seria possível uma das colunas da matriz conter checkboxs? Por exemplo:

```
<input data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="name" value="John" >
```

Aguardo e obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

As linhas que criam a célula são

```
var texto=document.createTextNode(conteudo[i][o]);
t.appendChild(texto);
```

Repare que a variável `texto` é atribuída com o resultado de um chamado à função `createTextNode`, que cria um nó de texto com a string fornecida como parâmetro. Se você fornecer uma tag a essa função, ela vai escapar os caracteres especiais pra imprimir o valor como texto.

Como você quer um checkbox, é necessário criar um nó HTML ao invés de um nó de texto. É possível definir um HTML diretamente através do atributo [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

No exemplo que você postou, o efeito é facilmente obtido substituindo o trecho que eu destaquei com esse:

```
t.innerHTML = conteudo[i][o];
```

E então todos os valores serão considerados como HTML, aí vc pode fazer:

```
document.getElementById("tabela").appendChild(criarTabela([
  ["id", "nome",     "idade", "habilitado"],
  [1,    "matheus",  16, '<input type="checkbox">']
]));
```

Note que como estamos usando a mesma função pra inserir HTML e dados, dependendo da origem dos dados pode haver risco de um ataque [XSS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Ou ainda que a origem seja segura, se a entrada tiver caracteres especiais HTML, pode haver efeitos indesejados. Se isso for uma preocupação, o ideal seria usar um código personalizado pra gerar sua tabela.

Comment: muito obrigado! Resolveu meu problema ;D
nunca tinha mexido com js, preciso estudar mais rs

Comment: Se tá começando agora recomendo a leitura do excelente artigo no MDN [Introdução ao DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Introduction) pra aprender a manipular o documento HTML com JavaScript.

Comment: valeu ;D irei ler o/

Comment: Se minha resposta foi útil não se esqueça de votar a favor e aceitá-la como correta :)

Answer (score 1):

Cara, tenho uma solução que pode lhe ajudar.

```
    String.prototype.template = function (obj) {
        return this.replace(/\{\{([\w]+)\}\}/g, function (str, prop) {
            return obj[prop];
        });
    };

    var varString = '<input data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="name" value="{{id}}"> {{nome}}';

    var users = [
        {
            id      : 1,
            nome    : "matheus",
            idade   : 16
        },{
            id      : 2,
            nome    : "cristian",
            idade   : 16
        },{
            id      : 3,
            nome    : "pedro",
            idade   : 10
        },{
            id      : 4,
            nome    : "henrique",
            idade   : 10
        }
    ];

    var result = "";

    users.forEach(function(obj, index){
        result += varString.template(obj);
    }); 

    document.write(result);
```